# Display sponsor server different color not showing php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am wondering why my sponsored servers are not being highlighted?

```
<?php
require_once('mysql_connect.php');

$query  =   "SELECT id, name, banner, description, sponsor, votes, hits FROM websites ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 50";
$result =   mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
// Rank counter
$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //it would wrap your text upto 20 characters 
    $wrappedText = wordwrap(substr($row['description'], 0, 200), 55, "<br />\n", true);

    if(sponsor == 0){
        echo '<tbody>
    <tr class="server glossed site">
        <td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        '.$rank.'</td>
        <td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" rel="no_follow" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
        $wrappedText.'</p></td>
        <td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tbody>
    <tr class="server sponsor site">
        <td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        '.$rank.'</td>
        <td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" rel="no_follow" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
        $wrappedText.'</p></td>
        <td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    }
$rank++;
}
?>
```

I have added the CSS , i belive..

```
 .server.sponsor{
    background-color:#9dd0f6;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #aaa
}
```

But it will not show up as the color chosen for sponsor site.

Comment: Does the resulting HTML show the rows with the right class? Does your browser's inspector show another rule overriding the styling? What basic troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: No it does not show up as sponsored when i inspect element

Comment: Then check the value of $sponsor. Should it be $row['sponsor']?

Answer (score 0):

`if(sponsor == 0){` is both not valid PHP and `$sponsor` is never set. You likely want `$row['sponsor']`.